Jenkins Json parser encases double quotes on the value of a field that has an object
The jenkins json parser is placing quotes on a value of a field that has a object encased in open and closed brackets.
This is the correct json before it's added to the main object:
{"commands":[{"ack_token":"","name":"fullupdaterequest","params":{}}]}
This is what happens after the json above is added and then serialized:
{"method":"get","uut":{"password":"extron","ip":"10.113.90.120","username":"admin"},"conn_id":"2f01acb3sf03es4478sa5eds0c184d0f851e","params":"{"commands":[{"ack_token":"","name":"fullupdaterequest","params":{}}]}","command":"rawgm"}
I tried doing a find and replace but it doesn't work. Any ideas on some alternative way of getting rid of those quotes, maybe a regex, not certain how to get that to work without a lot of trail and error. Any ideas much appreciated, Thx.

How do you add it to "the main object"?

I kindly request that you format the code.

I realized the problem I was serializing the object when adding it to the field. When I just added the object to the field and then serialized it fixed it.

I realized the problem I was serializing the object when adding it to the field. When I just added the object to the field and then serialized it fixed it. –

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
